# Save the progress in AVPlayer to update a UIProgressView and resume from the same place later

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audio

I am looking for some basic help with a stumbling block I've encountered coding an app for my school. I am new to Swift so I apologize in advance if this is silly query.

I am programming an app that will play audio and remembers the progress of audio files if you close the app and return later. The problem I'm having is the app remembering your progress, which is pretty key.

I am using the AVPlayer controller object.

I am new to stackoverflow, if someone would be able to walk me through this question or even point me in the right direction I would greatly greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out! UserDefaults is what I was looking for, I just stored the progress as a key and used the key to update to progress whenever the app is loaded.